# FPPopover doesn't present popover View iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, popover

I'm trying to use FPPopover to open a notifications view, It works on iOS 5 on the app but doesn't show up on iOS 6. However, if i use the same code for a different project doing just that, it does show for both iOS 5 & 6

This is what i did in both projects.

```
- (IBAction)NotificationButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self openNotificationsPopOver:sender];
}

- (void)openNotificationsPopOver:(id)sender {
    [self setNotificationCount:0];

    NotificationViewController *vc = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Notification" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotificationViewController"];

//    NotificationViewController *vc = [[NotificationViewController alloc]init];
//    [vc setParentViewController:self];


    FPPopoverController *popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:vc];

    //sender is the UIButton view
    [popover presentPopoverFromView:sender];

    //popover.arrowDirection = FPPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    popover.tint = FPPopoverDefaultTint;

    popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 250);

    popover.arrowDirection = FPPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    NSLog(@"Present popover");
    //sender is the UIButton view
    [popover presentPopoverFromView:sender];
//    [popover presentPopoverFromPoint:CGPointMake(160, 0)];

//sender is the UIButton view
//    [popover presentPopoverFromView:self.navigationController.navigationBar];
}
```

i tried using the lines commented out for it as well... all methods work on the separate project (iOS 5 & 6) but on the main project it only works on iOS 5

Also tried removing the frameworks and adding them again. Started this project with xCode 4.3 (dunno if it matters).

Reference: https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover

Comment: Maybe it's worth filing a bug report with the creator? There may be a bug somewhere in the code. I'm just about to start using it in my project now so if I run into a similar problem and can sort it I'll let you know :)

Comment: thnx, i'm using modal popover for now

Comment: What's happening when you call **presentPopoverFromView** ? Nothing? Is it crashing?

Comment: Nothing happens... i've been moved to another area tho... but ideas on fixing it would be great. i still have the old codes... haven't done anything with popover since..

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure the "window" is instantiated BEFORE alloc and present the popover.

Comment: What u mean ? It works in iOS 5 on the app and both iOS 5&6 on a different app with same code... Literally copy pasted into new project ( which works )